# difference between two consecutive date in days in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Following is the company table, I need to get difference between two consecutive dates in no of days based on companyId and `rownum`

```
company_id  date    row_num
101         2017-01-12              1
101         2017-02-22              2
118         2017-03-23              1
119         2017-04-18              1
123         2017-01-12              1
123         2017-01-15              2
123         2017-01-22              3
501         2017-01-30              1
501         2017-02-02              2
```

Expected OutPut:

```
company_id  date    days
101         2017-01-12              0
101         2017-02-22              41
118         2017-03-23              0
119         2017-04-18              0
123         2017-01-12              0
123         2017-01-15              3
123         2017-01-22              7
501         2017-01-30              0
501         2017-02-02              3
```

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can simply be done using self-join without the use of any analytic function since `row_num` is already available in the table.

```
SELECT  a.company_id, 
        a.billing_failure_date, 
        a.row_num,
        ISNULL(DATEDIFF (d, b.billing_failure_date, a.billing_failure_date), 0) AS Days
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN TableName b
            ON a.company_id = b.company_id
                AND a.row_num = b.row_num + 1
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/215f0/1).

Answer (score 1):

**FOR BELOW SQL 2012 use this**

```
SELECT * , ISNULL(DATEDIFF( DAY , 
            ( SELECT TOP 1 billing_failure_date FROM companyTable b WHERE a.company_id = b.company_id
                AND a.billing_failure_date > b.billing_failure_date 
            ORDER BY  billing_failure_date DESC ) ,billing_failure_date),0) Days
FROM companyTable a
```

**OUTPUT**

```
company_id  billing_failure_date row_num     Days
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
101         2017-01-12           1           0
101         2017-02-22           2           41
118         2017-03-23           1           0
119         2017-04-18           1           0
123         2017-01-12           1           0
123         2017-01-15           2           3
123         2017-01-22           3           7
501         2017-01-30           1           0
501         2017-02-02           2           3

(9 rows affected)
```

FOR SQL 2012+ **Please try this solution-**

```
SELECT * , 
DATEDIFF( DAY , 
ISNULL(LAG(billing_failure_date) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY billing_failure_date ASC),billing_failure_date)
,billing_failure_date) Days
FROM companyTable
```

**OUTPUT**

```
company_id  billing_failure_date row_num     Days
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
101         2017-01-12           1           0
101         2017-02-22           2           41
118         2017-03-23           1           0
119         2017-04-18           1           0
123         2017-01-12           1           0
123         2017-01-15           2           3
123         2017-01-22           3           7
501         2017-01-30           1           0
501         2017-02-02           2           3

(9 rows affected)
```

Comment: OP mentioned he is using SQL 2008, 2005 .

Comment: I've seen your articles on SQL puzzles .they where amazing . Impressive .

Comment: Thank you Mahesh.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2008 and down:

```
    ; WITH T (Company_Id, Billing_Failure_Date , RowNum )
    AS
    (
        SELECT 101, '2017-01-12', 1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 101, '2017-02-22', 2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 118, '2017-03-23', 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 119, '2017-04-18', 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 123, '2017-01-12', 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 123, '2017-01-15', 2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 123, '2017-01-22', 3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 501, '2017-01-30', 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 501, '2017-02-02', 2
    )

    , W AS 
    (
    SELECT * , (SELECT MAX(Ottr.Billing_Failure_Date) FROM T Ottr WHERE Ottr.Company_Id = Innr.Company_Id AND Ottr.RowNum < Innr.RowNum AND Ottr.Billing_Failure_Date < Innr.Billing_Failure_Date) Prev_Billing_Failure_Date
    FROM T Innr
    )
    SELECT Company_Id, Billing_Failure_Date , RowNum , ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,Prev_Billing_Failure_Date, Billing_Failure_Date),0) [Days]
    FROM W
```